# ffmpeg change file while streaming

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm busy with FFmpeg streaming to a RTMP server.
What I'm trying to do is stream a png file that changes content.
The PNG file is been created by PhantomJS every 1 second.
The file is not bigger then 2MB.

when the content of the PNG file is changed, I get the error:

> [png @ 0xe91740] chunk too big
> Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

This works fine but it breaks at some point with:

> [flv @ 0xe8a9c0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
>
> [flv @ 0xe8a9c0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.

I know the problem is caused because FFmpeg still remembers the previous file data, and encoded the new file with those settings.

This is the command line I use:

```
 ffmpeg -y -re -stream_loop -1 -f image2 -i image.png -strict -1 \
 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1000k \
 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -threads 1 -f flv rtmp://server/live/test \
 -nostdin -nostats -hide_banner > /dev/null &
```

I use Ubuntu Server.

Comment: The image update has to be atomic. Write to file1.png and then `mv file1.png file2.png`. Feed `file2.png` to ffmpeg. You can also add `-framerate 5` to increase read interval by ffmpeg, and add `-r 25` to restore output framerate.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @drkostas I solved it with the help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21405279/988591. Basically I wrote some code that detects changes to the image (using the Watchdog lib) and when that happens 1) it reads the image file, 2) it prepares (opens) another file for writing, 3) moves the writing head (seek) at the beginning it, 4) commits the writing operation to it. This way of isolating the various operations seems to guarantee that the actual write operation (#4) is atomic and in my case it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Redoman I used this library and worked like a charm: https://python-atomicwrites.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @drkostas yeah I tried that lib but in my case it didn't work; for some reason my code was still causing non-atomic updates, so in the end I had to do it manually as I said above and it worked.

Comment: @red-o-alf I am facing similar issue, i believe your advice will be helpful, i am using docker ffmpeg to generate 3 rtmp from three different images, currently i am using python to create a tmp image first, verify it is valid, then call `os.rename` to update path, but i still got following error, any idea?

[image2 @ 0xaaab139e3060] Could not open file : /data/objects_right.jpg
[in#0/image2 @ 0xaaab139e2f40] Error during demuxing: Input/output error
[in#0/image2 @ 0xaaab139e2f40] Error retrieving a packet from demuxer: Input/output error